# Best way to bind data from AdapterView into RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-adapterview

I'm new to Java and programming as a whole. And i've been trying to get a result set from JSON put in a Simple Adapter to load data into TextView's contained in a RelativeLayout. A link or any help in the right direction would be much appreciated, thanks in Advance.
Kind Regards.

```
            /**
                     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
                     * **/
                    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        // updating UI from Background Thread
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                /**
                                 * Updating parsed JSON data into RelativeLayout
                                 * */
                                AdapterView adapter = new AdapterView(
                                        AllProductsActivity.this, productsview,
                                        R.layout.sample_view, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                                TAG_NAME},
                                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                                // updating View view
                                setAdapter(adapter);
                            }
                        });

                    }

                }
            }
```

Here is a look at my XML File

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/sample_view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pid"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
                    android:text="Product ID"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                    android:text="Product Name"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a simple case like this, you can use `ArrayAdapter<String>`. `AdapterView` is the parent of classes like `ListView`. It mainly defines `View`s which children will be determined by an `Adapter`; it is not the `Adapter` itself.